# Node vs Chrome, assigning console.log to a variable?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, v8, chromium, console.log

When I assign `console.log` to a variable in node.js it works fine,

```
var l = console.log
l(1) # outputs 1
```

However, if I do the same thing in Chromium 30's dev tools,

```
var l = console.log
l(1) # TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

How come it doesn't work in Chromium's dev tools? Why am I getting,

> TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: It works in Firefox, why not use Firefox?

Answer (score 6):

Exactly *why* this requirement is in place, I don't know, but I guess Chrome's `console.log` requires the value of `this` to be `console`. If you want to store it in a variable, you'll have to bind the value of `this`:

```
var l = console.log.bind(console);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Node.js console does `console.log = console.log.bind(this)` in constructor](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L46-L49).